# Destribution of classes in training set

Tags: machine-learning, classification

When making a predictive model (specificly in telecommunication regarding churn), is it essential to have a 1:1 split between the classes in the training set(the actual distribution is more like 1:50)? When reading on what other people have done this seems to be the case. But they dont neccesarily state it as a requirement. What is recommended?

Comment: I think your question would attract more attention on stats.stackexchange.com ;  However, I will give the attempt of an answer (to a relatively general question) below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is frequently referred to as "Class Imbalance". Whether and how it will impact your result depends on the algorithm and the evaluation metric you use. The logistic regression algorithm, and the model accuracy, for example, can be very susceptible to this problem. Simple envelope models, and the model AUC, on the other hand, are more resilient against class imbalance. I am aware of five broad possible approaches to deal with this:

1) Up-sampling: Basically artificially increase the number of the rare class. This may be the go-to solution when you have very little data but you are confident that it is quite representative of the wider population.

2) Down-sampling: Just leave out a part of the abundant class. This is an option when you have a very large quantity of data.

3) Weighting: Telling your algorithm to give more importance to the information obtained from the rare class.

4) Bagging: Here, you are randomly sub-sampling your data and fitting "weak" learners to each subsample. Later, these weak learners are aggregated to create one final prediction.

5) Boosting: Similar to bagging, but each "weak" learner is not agnostic to the previously fitted one. Instead, they take the residuals from the latest ensemble.

There is a [really nice article here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/03/imbalanced-classification-problem/) that goes through these in great detail, including some worked examples in `R`, and [another one here](https://svds.com/learning-imbalanced-classes/) which focuses more on `python`

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed!